# Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors, shows no errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've created a table `tr_startup_audit`

Then I created a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tr_startup_audit
after startup on database
begin
insert into startup_audit values(
ora_sysevent,
sysdate,
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'hh24:mm:ss'));
end;
/
```

When I compile it, it shows

> "Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors."

When I do `show err` command it shows

> "no errors"

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No problem for me:

```
SQL> create table startup_audit (event varchar2(30), datum date, sat varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger tr_startup_audit
  2  after startup on database
  3  begin
  4  insert into startup_audit values(
  5  ora_sysevent,
  6  sysdate,
  7  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'hh24:mm:ss'));
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**However**:

- why are you storing time component separately? `DATE` datatype (which means `SYSDATE` function as well, as it returns `DATE`), contain both date and time

  ```
  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

  Session altered.

  SQL> select sysdate from dual;

  SYSDATE
  -------------------
  06.07.2021 08:28:56
  ```

  Therefore, you can omit line #7 and store just `sysdate` (line #6).

  Certainly, it means that you should redefine the `startup_audit` table as well and remove column you're now using to store "invalid" time. Why is it invalid? Read on.
- format mask you used in `to_char` is wrong. `mm` is for *months*, while `mi` is for *minutes*